# JSON Customizado para DataAnnotations - Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Boa tarde!

Tenho uma Web API em .Net Core, em que tenho a seguinte classe de requisição para uma rota POST:

```
public class CreateAgentRequest
{
    [Required]
    public Agent Agent { get; set; }
}
```

Com a Annotation Required, se eu não mando um campo `Agent`, ele me retorna o erro na seguinte estrutura da chamada da API

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, eu tenho um Model customizado de validação, que são validações que eu não trato com Data Annotations, como por exemplo, que esse dado já existe na base de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho a necessidade de customizar esse retorno da Data Annotation (primeira imagem), para seguir o mesmo padrão da segunda imagem. Há alguma forma de customizar o retorno da validação de Data Annotation?

Comment: required é um ValidationAttribute. Uma opção seria implementar o seu atributo personalizado, por exemplo RepresentanteUnicoAttribute, e utilizá-lo no pipeline de validação. Exemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde

Você pode customizar uma mensagem de erro utilizando a DataAnnotation.ErrorMessage

```
public class CreateAgentRequest
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Mensagem de Erro")]
    public Agent Agent { get; set; }
}
```

Agora se você deseja retorno o mesmo objeto da segunda imagem tenta dar uma verificada em DataAnnotation.CustomValidation, eu sei que com ele tu consegue personalizar uma Validation, e imagino que o retorno dela também.